# SSD is detected, but Computer doesn't boot from it anymore

Tags: boot, bios, hardware-failure

Suddenly, without making any changes to my hardware, my notebook doesn't boot anymore.
After the BIOS, the screen goes blank and the system just reboots with no error message. I have multiple OS installed, so usually there is the Win7 OS selection screen. The boot process doesn't even get as far as this screen.
Things I tried:

- BIOS Reset
- Booting into the EASEUS Boot CD does work. (this is a boot CD for disk partitioning). It does recognize the SSD and all partitions on it.
- The SSD seems to be okay. When attached to another computer, it is readable.
- The BIOS self-diagonstic (incl. memory test) showed no problems
- Detaching all USB devices
- Running with only one stick of RAM (tried both)

Any ideas what else I could try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try reinstalling your operating system.

It is possible that your hardware is completely fine and this is purely a software related error.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I installed Windows 7 onto a VHD. The installation process apparently fixed my boot record, and now everything works again.